# nginx /admin /login wordpress

Tags: nginx, wordpress, rewrite

I want to setup simpler urls in nginx to login into wordpress i.e. /admin /login in nginx

I have tried multiple ways of tackling this with no luck. any ideas?

currently working with this, but I know it's not working

`if ($uri ~* "/login") { 
 rewrite ^(.*)$ http://$host/wp-admin/;
}`

Final Working Version:
`if ($uri ~* "/login") {
  rewrite ^/login(/.*)? /wp-admin$1;
}`

Comment: Please show us all the ways which you had tried?

Comment: good point, I just posted what I am working with

Comment: What did you get when you access `http://$host/login` in browser? Did you take a look at error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewriting works largely the same as in Apache, but with different syntax:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule

Something like this should do the trick:

```
rewrite ^/admin(/.*)? /wp-admin$1
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help, I was able to use your segment to add the "login" I wanted.

`# short cuts
 if ($uri ~* "/login") {
  rewrite ^/login(/.*)? /wp-admin$1;
}
`